# Redirect Domain & Sub-domain to HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I am trying to redirect my domain and sub domain to https. I have subscribed to Wildcard SSL and made below modifications to htaccess file, as per [this guide](https://in.godaddy.com/help/redirect-http-to-https-automatically-8828).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I am now seeing HTTPS 'Secure Connection' on my main domain. But on sub-domain, it is still showing 'Not Secure' although HTTPS is in the domain.
[image]
What changes do I do here to redirect my subdomain as well to https 'Secure Connection'.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a problem with your cert installation or signing, that is why it shows "Not Secure".

You may want to try to check if the cert is correctly installed using some checker tool:
Example. https://cryptoreport.websecurity.symantec.com/checker/

Or check with your cert and hosting provider for assistance to see if it is your cert installation or signing problem.

Comment: Thanks. For the main domain, the feedback received was "Self-signed certificate is installed". The main domain looks alright "Certificate is installed correctly". What should I do?

Comment: check with your cert and hosting provider for the correct steps to install your cert, or the correct settings to protect both your main and sub domains with your wildcard ssl.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply/check other .htaccess file(s) in your sub-domain(s) root directories. Example `subdomain.yourmaindomain` may be located at `root/subdomain` folder (need be checked - it's depended to your subdomain setting).

Comment: It is a wordpress multisite setup. So they share the same htaccess file.